# Sans-serif cross reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, sans-serif

I'd like my cross reference to be formatted in sans-serif, but I've not been able to find the way.

I'm currently using both `cleveref` and `hyperref` packages.

Comment: We've got a nice concept here: Providing a starter document ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a I know there's no way to use `\crefdefaultlabelformat` in order to query the current counter type to be referenced and thereby getting the relevant name of the counter as being defined with `\crefname` and `\Crefname`.

However, the `\crefformat` can be used to change the specific formating with to sans-serif with this setup (shown for the section counter)

```
\crefformat{section}{#2{\sffamily\cref@section@name\ #1}#3}
```

The same can be done for `\Crefformat`, replacing `\cref@section@name` by `\Cref@section@name`)

As it stands, the `\crefmultiformat` and `\crefrangeformat` commands are not changed (yet).

In order to prevent tedious code copying, I've provided a way with `expl3` syntax to store the counter types to a `\seq` list and then changing the format in a loop within `\switchtosansserifformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\seq_new:N \l_atcold_counter_seq 

\newcommand{\addcountertoseq}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_atcold_counter_seq {#1}
}

\newcommand{\switchtosansserifformat}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_atcold_counter_seq {%
    \crefformat{##1}{####2{\protect\sffamily\use:c{cref@##1@name}\ ####1}####3}
    \Crefformat{##1}{####2{\protect\sffamily\use:c{Cref@##1@name}\ ####1}####3}
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\addcountertoseq{section,subsection,subsubsection,figure,table,page}

\switchtosansserifformat
\begin{document}
Outlook: In \cref{foo} we will see that ... and \cref{foofigure} shows that ... and \cref{footable} has the relevant data

Outlook: In \Cref{foo} we will see that ... and \Cref{foofigure} shows that ... and \Cref{footable} has the relevant data


\clearpage

\section{Foo} \label{foo}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A foo figure}\label{foofigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A foo table}\label{footable}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMG! This is **a lot of** code! I thought this was a common will and that I could have called `cleverref` with an additional parameter or smartly using `\crefdefaultlabelformat`... That's why there is no starter document in my question: I was expecting a one-line answer. Therefore, although your answer address correctly my question, I'll wait before accepting it, hoping for a one-liner.

Comment: @Atcold: Yes, that would be really nice, but redefining `cleveref` code would not be simpler, in my point of view. If you don't like the `expl3` list, you have to use `\crefformat` for each counter name. If I would knew a shorter version (=better version?) I would post it, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you are iterating here. But I was convinced I did ask a dummy question due to my lack of experience with LaTeX. Btw, thank you very much for your input!

Comment: @Atcold: I'll try to look into `\crefdefaultlabelformat`, perhaps it's possible with a `one-liner` ;-) -- Oh my, very tricky. At the moment, I think, my version is the shortest one, but let's wait ;-)

Comment: Hold on, I may have a suggestion. What I actually wanted was to have all 'links' (the stuff that `hyperref` colours up) in a more visible character, like sans-serif. Maybe 'we' could add that in addition to the colour change. What do you think?

Comment: @Atcold: No,sorry, that wasn't your question. You asked explicitly for cross references (`cleveref`), not about changing the style how all links do appear!

Comment: Hmm... The bibliography citations are cross references, aren't they? You can click on them and you get to the correct location. Would that make things easier?

Comment: @Atcold: No, not really. If you're not satisfied, I will delete my post

Comment: Your answer has been marked as *accepted* because it does answer my question. I will create a new question where I will address a different need. Thank you for your time. I didn't want to sound rude or disrespectful.